# Accessing a web site externally published through TMG from the internal network

Tags: windows, outlook-web-app, tmg

I have a TMG2010 instance with 3 internal networks and 2 external networks (all on separate network cards).

I have published Outlook Web Access via TMG using one of the external addresses. I want to be able to access this site from the internal networks as well as the external however I cannot make this happen. I do not want to have to use a DNS override to point at an internal address as this seems to confuse smart phones when they switch between the internal Wi-Fi and external/3G networks.

My publishing rule accepts requests from "anywhere"; my SSL listener listens on the external addresses only. I have a global "catch all" rule that allows "all outbound protocols" from internal to external.

Externally, OWA works without any problem. If however I try to access from one of the internal networks I cannot reach the server.

OWA is published on the same address as is used for all outbound traffic to the Internet.

Can anybody offer any advice?

Comment: 1. Is the internal DNS suffix of the server the same as the outside?
2. When you resolve the external FQDN of your server from inside, do you get the proper result?

Comment: The internal suffix differs from the external; internally we are .local and externally we are .co.uk - if we ping the external name we do resolve to the correct external address, however that address does not respond to a ping.